# How can I modify the context menu of discord? (BetterDiscord)

Tags: javascript, css, discord

Apologies if this has been asked before, I've been searching for a lot of solutions and I can't seem to find anything that would help.

A note before reading this, I am clueless when it comes to JavaScript, CSS and HTML.
Essentially, BetterDiscord has a copy selector button which you can turn on which doesn't suit the rest of the context menu, it's un-styled. Obviously, copying the entire div class of the previous button and overwriting it works, however I only know how to do that using inspect element.

[image: before modifying the html]

This is before modifying the HTML, although after pasting the whole div class from another button (`item-1Yvehc itemBase-tz5SeC da-item da-itemBase clickable-11uBi- da-clickable`) to the other button (copy selector, which doesnt have a div, it's just a span) it becomes styled like the rest of the context menu. All I want to do is to either be able to rewrite it's HTML with CSS or JavaScript. The selector for all the buttons is called `item-1Yvehc itemBase-tz5SeC`, although the copy selector button only has `item-1Yvehc` Willing to be guided, thank you. Video guiding how I fix the problem temporarily:
https://youtu.be/ozJK7K898gQ